# Clear GET or POST data from CGI script?

Tags: server

I'm making a toy LAN messaging system that involves Ruby CGI scripts and data files stored on the server, and I want to prevent the same data from being sent to the server multiple times.

Is there any way that you know of to request that the client of your web server forget the GET or POST data that it sent in its request?

Comment: I'm not sure this goes here.  I'll ask it on Pro Webmasters and then flag it.

Comment: Got it.  I was trying to use an HTTP header to redirect to "/" from "index.cgi", but changed to redirecting to "index.cgi" after seeing wolfie's post at http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/clear-get-post-value-on-refresh-page-69657.html.

Comment: If you answered your own question, you should post it as an answer, then when the time period expires mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I was trying to use an HTTP header to redirect to "/" from "index.cgi", but changed to redirecting to "index.cgi" after seeing wolfie's post at http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/clear-get-post-value-on-refresh-page-69657.html.